# Authlogic Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Which version of authlogic are people using with Rails 3.1.

I have the following entry in my gemfile:

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'https://github.com/AndreasWurm/authlogic.git'
```

The problem I have is with a piece of code in my base ApplicationController.

```
def require_no_user
  if current_user
    store_location
    flash[:notice] = "You must be logged out to access this page"
    redirect_to :controller => "home", :action => "index"
    return false
  end
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end
```

The error I am getting is with the line:

```
session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x7dadd4d8>
```

Has Request_uri been removed from ActionDispatch and if so, what is the correct alternative?

Answer (score 30):

The best solution is as said [Vadim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848505/vadim-chumel), using the new methods in ActionDispatch::Request :

You just replace :

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end
```

by :

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.url
end
```

and it's done !

Answer (score 7):

[fullpath](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/fullpath) will give you url(but without protocol, port, domain) with params
and `request.url` will give you everything that `fullpath` skips